# convert image local path to base64 ionic 5

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

So I'm training to convert local path image to base64 using [base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/base64) plugin

but the result is empty

```
 showCroppedImage(ImagePath) {

     let filePath: string = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.test.app/cache/1662048635837-cropped.jpg';
     this.base64.encodeFile(ImagePath).then((base64File: string) => {
       console.log('base64: ' + base64File); // result is empty 
     }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
     });
  }
```

I can not us [file plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/file) because if conflicting With file mothod of javascript

Comment: What is the "file method" of Javascript? And note that using `file:///` is guaranteed to not work if the actual code doesn't run in file context, rather than web context, which it almost certainly won't be.

Comment: The file method I'm talking about is this (new File([this.imageBlob], imageName, { type: 'image/jpeg' })) is stop working when i install the file plugin

Comment: it doesn't: it'll throw an error, so what's that error.

Comment: Can you specify how you get the file path?

Comment: Using camera plugin and crop plugin